# Why does an M1 MBP incorrectly recognize a monitor that a 2015 MBP gets right?

Tags: display, resolution, apple-silicon

The M1 machine incorrectly detects the high res monitor in some way, and thus does not allow Display Scaling to work correctly.  There is [some coverage](https://www.theregister.com/2021/12/03/apple_m1_drivers?page=2) of this issue, but I'm trying to understand why it happens.

The scenario:

i.e. when the external monitor is set to full 4k, the text is tiny - and this is because OSX doesn't allow me to use the Display Scaling feature.

1. Both machines are running the same version of MacOS (Monterrey).
2. The monitor is 4k (3840 x 2160), by UPERFECT, and has USB-C and HDMI ports.   The
3. MBPs each have USB and HDMI ports
4. The issue happens regardless of which combination of ports are use

I understand that some people [use BetterDummy to solve this problem](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDummy), but I'm trying to understand *Why* it is happening.   I know [this article](https://www.theregister.com/2021/12/03/apple_m1_drivers?page=2) makes some reference to the monitors being unrecognized, but what about them is different from a another monitor that works correctly?

**with correct scaling**

[image: with correct scaling]

**incorrect scaling**

[image: incorrect scaling]

Comment: Will you be describing what is happening?

Comment: What model is the monitor?

Comment: I've edited to re-emphase the problem that the linked article also talks about

Comment: Which display is affected? I wonder if Apple has to program in driver details for some displays due to how they report their capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX Ventura (13.0 Beta (22A5266r)) now supports retina and limited scaling support via a setting called "HiDPI".  For some displays, it may only be visible by clicking "Show All Resolutions".

Upgrading to the beta OS or waiting for the support to hit the mainline seems to be path for everyone now.

Comment: Is that new? MacOS has had the ability to show a larger list of resolutions, including "hiDPI" scaled ones, for years.

Comment: per the question, this is contextual to specific displays that were slow to get support.  In my case, it was a UPERFECT model 15" UHD display (3840x2160)

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, the "why" is simply because the two machines are vastly different.

Hardware, firmware, drivers, software, etc. on the Intel Mac and the M1 Mac for displays are simply vastly different. Apple reimplemented most of this part of the stack regarding detecting displays and recognising their capabilities for the Apple Silicon-based Macs.

You already have advise on how to actually solve the problem for you, so I'm not going to expand on that. However, if you would like the initial problem fixed, I will recommend reporting it to Apple as a bug. There's then hope it will be fixed in an upcoming release of macOS.

Comment: The linked article provided the general answer.  Thanks if you can update your answer with specifics on why the M1 arch doesn't allow scaling to be enabled ('unless monitor has XYZ hardware signature', whatever)

Comment: There’s nothing specific about the M1 arch that doesn’t allow scaling to be enabled. This has nothing to do at all with it being an M1 as such. It’s just that the firmware and  drivers for this new hardware is new and different. So you will have places where things work differently than in the past, and you will have bugs. The best to do is to report the bug, and if it is a pain for you, open a support case with Apple.